# Override outlook.com esxMscNormal to have no margin?

Tags: css, html-email, outlook-2010

I am working on an email signiture sent from outlook desktop 2010.  The template is looking ok in most clients, but when testing against outlook.com it seems to be inserting paragraphs around table cell text with a class of esxMscNormal with a 19pt bottom margin and breaking the whole design.  Two days in and i can't seem to get it to work or find anything that allows me to override it.

Does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are creating the whole email in html, try adding this to your head section style tag:

```
#outlook a {padding:0;}
```

If that doesn't work you could try adding `!important`

If it is just an email signature, and not a full html document, there is no way to put in a `<style>` tag declaration there. This is the only way to overwrite a `<p>` tag that doesn't exist yet.

Best way in this case is to just try to design around it.

Comment: Nothing can be done, signature was simplified to cater for it, but it still broke in outlook.com and not in others, was allowed to go through in the end as there is no way to fix it.

Comment: May be completely unrelated, but you haven't set any margin yourself have you? Outlook.com doesn't support margin.

Comment: Nope, its all to do with where the signiture comes in and the rubbish outlook.com pushes in.  When sent as a html email there are no issues.